# priorities upload priority to give high priority to slingbox using htb qdiscs

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I am trying to set slingbox connection to class 1:20 using the following commands:

iptables -t mangle -A to-cable -p tcp --dport 5001 -j CLASSIFY --set-class 1:20
iptables -t mangle -A to-cable -p tcp --sport 5001 -j CLASSIFY --set-class 1:20

i have other class related commands for ssh, http and news.

i use the command 'tc -s class ls dev eth0' to view what's going on and there is no data transfer through class 1:20 even when i'm connected to slingbox.
the rest of the ports (ssh,http,news) are forwarded through the class properly.

is there any better way to catch slingbox data transfer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the iptables built-in module iprange.
so i set the class to be configured for any data from the slingbox's ip address instead of a specific port.